# How to create a contextual filter to be used as the first character for a field?

Tags: views

I create a view listing a field called `authors` the page path `miSite.com/authors`

Then if I load this page I get the results:

```
Bach
Vivaldi
Vaccaro
Babbitt
```

This view page has the path: `miSite.com/authors`

I need to create a contextual filter to filter the result for the first character of the author field. I should work in this way:

1) If I load:

```
miSite.com/authors/b
```

I get the results:

```
Bach
Babbitt
```

---

2) If I load:

```
miSite.com/authors/v
```

I get the results:

```
Vivaldi
Vaccaro
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a contextual filter for the node title and configure it in "glossary mode". Provide a fixed value "a" and check the glossary mode settings at the bottom of the settings page.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was this option in the contextual filter settings.